# Why am I getting random numbers when I try to increase the ascii value of a char?

Tags: c, string, ascii

```
int n = argv[i][j];
n = n + (int)argv[1]; 

/* I'm pretty sure the above part that is wrong. What I was hoping that this 
would do is take the number the person put in and increase n by that number but 
it isnt working*/ 

printf("%d\n", n);
```

- i = the string numbers of the argument
- j = the characters of the string

What I want is to make it so when someone types `./123 12 hi` I want it to increase the ascii characters of `h` and `i` by 12 or whatever number they put in. When I test my code out with

```
./123 1 hi
```

I get an output of

```
-1081510229
-1081510228
```

instead of

```
105
106
```

which is `i` and `j`, the next letters of `h` and `i`

Libraries I'm using

```
stdio.h 
studio50.h
string.h
```

Comment: `argv[1]` is a `char*` pointing to `"1"`, not an `int` with value `1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`argv[1]` is a string (i.e, a null-terminated char array), casting it to `int` doesn't give the result you expected

You should use `atoi` to do the job. Or better, use `strtol` to get better stability.

Comment: If you don't want to have undefined behaviour if the user types in rubbish, you can use `strtol` instead of `atoi`.

Comment: lol im so dumb... I remembered reading about this but I forgot about it... Thanks~